# UTM conversion to Lat/Lon using Karney equations in script is off by 0.05 degree latitude - why?

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

I have translated the Karney provided equations from the javascript at https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy/blob/master/utm.js to translate UTM to Lat/Lon into a different scripting language for a project to translate shapefiles to map files for a satellite visualization tool.  When I run what purports to be a WGS-84 UTM shapefile it translates the lat/lon points into maps that are 0.05 degrees too far north.  I have tried using other datums (Clarke, GRS80) and they all seem to give virtually identical results using the semimajor values.  If I substitute the semiminor values the offset is greater.

I am checking the conversion results against a file of the same data that my source provided after running the data through ArcGIS to convert it to geographic directly.  I don't have access to ArcGIS, so I can't just do that.  I need an in-house more direct tool to integrate with our system.

I am not a math major, just an old line programmer, so I can't easily understand why this is happening.

Anybody got an idea about how I might fix this?

---

Here is the metadata from the UTM file I am converting followed by some points and conversions.  I have determined that for the initial points they are pretty much 6000 meters too far north.  I can get them within ~100 meters if I subtract 5500 meters before converting, so that suggests, since it doesn't get precisely there if I subtract 'exactly' 6000 meters, that the calculations are still off somewhere in the math.

20120510 
17021000 
Website\2012\Packages\ELEVATION\PackagedData_Statewide\Contours500Ft\Contours500Ft.shp
Projected
geogcsn Sync="TRUE" GCS_North_American_1983
projcsn Sync= "TRUE" NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_12N 
PROJCS ”NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_12N”, 
GEOGCS ”GCS_North_American_1983” 
DATUM ”D_North_American_1983”
SPHEROID ”GRS_1980”,6378137.0,298.257222101
PRIMEM ”Greenwich”,0.0
UNIT ”Degree” 0.0174532925199433
PROJECTION ”Transverse_Mercator”
PARAMETER ”False_Easting”,500000.0
PARAMETER ”False_Northing”,0.0
PARAMETER ”Central_Meridian”,-111.0
PARAMETER ”Scale_Factor”,0.9996
PARAMETER ”Latitude_Of_Origin”,0.0
UNIT ”Meter”,1.0
XOrigin -5120900
YOrigin -9998100
XYScale 450445547.3910538
ZOrigin 100000
ZScale 10000
MOrigin -100000
MScale 10000
XYTolerance 0.001
ZTolerance 0.001&
MTolerance 0.001&lt
HighPrecision true
bounds minlat="4094776.60000000" minlon="228582.50000000" maxlat="4653399.00000000" maxlon="673947.300000007"

UTM     CNV 
 lat = 4650693.00000000 lon = 389280.60000000   lat = 42.04826024690    lon = -112.33814680302
 lat = 4650348.50000000     lon = 389380.40000000   lat = 42.04517176050    lon = -112.33687612607
 lat = 4650360.00000000 lon = 389520.70000000   lat = 42.04529498908    lon = -112.33518315671
 lat = 4650690.50000000 lon = 389650.40000000   lat = 42.04828955593    lon = -112.33367812578
 lat = 4650673.00000000 lon = 390428.00000000   lat = 42.04824036112    lon = -112.32427926799
 lat = 4650328.50000000 lon = 390489.50000000   lat = 42.04514639600    lon = -112.32347200664

I did look at the Guidance 7-2 document that was suggested and I 'might' be able to convert the formulas to the scripting language, but it will probably cost me what little hair I have left on my head... the conversion from one language to another was relatively easy, but translating the formula direct may be above my rusted-out math skills.  I will check with our forecaster, he may be able to help me.

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be happening. Can you at least post a sample point, plus what you're getting and what it should be? Otherwise, you might try implementing the EPSG version of transverse Mercator from guidance note 7-2 (it will have a worked example. Or the one from John Snyder.